# Plugin with id Android not found

Tags: android, jenkins, android-gradle-plugin

New to jenkins and was running my first build. I am using gradle to do the build but kept getting the following error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* Where:
Build file '/Test/build.gradle' `line: 1'
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'ComitTest'.
> Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
> Plugin with id 'android' not found.
```

I have searched for almost 2 days and have tried installing other android plug ins but cant seem to solve this issue.

I have set up on jenkins the ANDROID_HOME variable under global properties. Made sure the path is correct.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post all of your "build.gradle" filse and the directory of the project.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it by adding the following code at the top of the bundle.gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'
    }
}
```

Thanks for your help :)