# Cordova plugin with id 'android' not found

Tags: android, cordova, exception

I was making some tests on a cordova app and everythings worked fine... unintentionally I closed the terminal (windows), and when I re-open it and try to make **cordova run android** (something that was working fine), it throws this error:

**EDIT *VERBOSE***

```
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
Preparing android project
Processing configuration changes for plugins.
Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'com.phonegap.plugins.PushPlugin',
  'com.simonmacdonald.telephonenumber',
  'cordova-plugin-whitelist',
  'nl.x-services.plugins.socialsharing',
  'org.apache.cordova.contacts',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.geolocation',
  'org.apache.cordova.media' ]
Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
Wrote out Android application name to "Nostro"
This app does not have launcher icons defined
Wrote out Android package name to "com.eatec.nostro"
Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat""
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Eloy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
WARNING : No target specified, deploying to device 'ZH80002TZ5'.
Running: C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuil dDebug -b C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\build.gradle' line: 22

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'android'.
    > Failed to apply plugin [id 'android']
       > Plugin with id 'android' not found.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug
option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.729 secs

C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\cordova\node_module\q\q.js:126
                throw e;
                      ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\build.gradle -PcdvBuildArch=arm -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\Eloy\Desktop\NOSTR\nostroApp\platforms\android\cordova\run.bat"
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
You may not have the required environment or OS to run this project
```

I think, that JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME are good configured, these are their values (shown by the cordova compilation proccess):

```
ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Eloy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45
```

Other possible important variables:

```
JDK_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%\bin
JRE_HOME: %JAVA_HOME%/jre
PATH: %SSL_HOME%;%NODE_HOME%;%MONGO_HOME%;%JDK_HOME%;%JRE_HOME%/bin;%ANT_HOME%/bin
```

Thank you very much.

**EDIT**

I tried with a fresh project, and it doesn't work. The steps I followed were:

```
cordova create aux  
cd aux  
cordova platform add android  
cordova run android
```

**EDIT**
I just tried to compile an app on Android Studio, and it works fine. What could be cordova doing wrong???

**EDIT**
mmmm!! curious!!! I try to compile the same project with my room PC, but before I make a fresh project with cordova, and how it was foreseeable, it works fine, so I was ready to run the main project, I typed comand, and after a few lines, it started to download http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.2.1-all.zip, and it download a lot of things, and finally it built succesfully, and install on my device.
Other thing that I discover is the that there are many differences on the contents of the folder project/platform/android between the main project (created on the laptop) and the test project (created on the pc). These are the main differences:
**Contents on the TestProject:** (folders) ant-build, ant-gen, (files) build.xml, custom_rules.xml, local.properties
**Contents on the MainProject:** (folders) gradle, (files) gradlew.bat, settings.gradle

The other files and folders are commons.

Comment: You can try to run it on *verbose* mode by using the `-d`switch as in `cordova run -d android`. That should give you more information. Anyway,  a `gradle` error can occur because of different reasons. I'd suggest to google for cordova and gradle errors.

Comment: try downloading cordova again with `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: Hi @GuillemVicens, and thanks for your help. I edited the question adding the error thrown with the verbose flag activated.

Comment: Hi @jcesarmobile I do it, but it doesn´t work... should I remove it before reinstall??

Comment: Hi again @jcesarmobile I have seen a little thing on the cordova installing:  npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.4","npm":"2.10.1"}) what I think understand is that cordova needs node 0.8 or node 0.10, and I have 0.12.... but is it really important??

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. And no, you don't have to remove it before reinstall

Comment: Ok!!! So... it isn´t the solution. It works and after close and open the cmd, it doesn´t work??? FRUSTRATION.

Comment: In some of your path variables you use / and in others \, as you are on windows, I think all should have /

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90513/discussion-between-eloy-fernandez-franco-and-jcesarmobile).

Comment: @EloyFernándezFranco, I posted this comment on chat, but then saw you are not anymore in it. You need to check your `build.gradle` file. There is some dependency or repository missing. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12569916/custom-gradle-plugin-id-not-found and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27347143/plugin-with-id-android-not-found for a couple of examples regarding this

Comment: Hi @GuillemVicens, thanks for answer. About _some dependency or repository missing_ where??? on the build.gradle?? I think no, because I test the project on my pc, and after download a significant amount of "things" (it is better explained on the last edit), the project was compiled and install on device. I copied/paste the project with ALL THE FOLDERS from my laptop to pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi @GuillemVicens and @jcesarmobile, finally it is working... @jcesarmobile told me about upgrade node and the first step to do that is:

```
npm cache clean
```

Once made that, and before upgrade, I try to compile and it thrown a new fail... but it was a problem with easy solution: open the console with admin privileges. I try to compile (cordova run android) again and IT WORKS :D

**EDIT**
I update too a lot of components of the Android SDK, but I think it wasn´t important, because I updated it yesterday, and make the first test today morning and it didn´t work, and after clean cache it does... so I think it was the key.

Muchas gracias Cesar.
Moltes gracies Guillem.

Answer (score 0):

check minsdk, maxsdk and target sdk versions - target sdk must be between min and max. i fixed issue buy setting

```
 <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
   <preference name="android-maxSdkVersion" value="23" />
   <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="16" />
```

Comment: Thanks @luttuandroid It seems that finallly I found the way to solve the problem, even I don´t remember at all what was :/